# Stroke effect with square cap

Tags: after-effects, animation, mask, motion-graphics

I'm trying to create a simple logo reveal, and have drawn a path over my logo like so:

[image]

It would be a lot easier if I could set the end points of my path so that they were square instead of rounded (like I can in Illustrator) but there appears to be no options for it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your strokes using the pen tool directly as a Shape Layer instead of the way you're doing it.
You will see an option for line caps and line joins. They can be round or square:
[image: grab]

To reveal the logo, put your original logo on the layer beneath the Shape Layer, then set the Track Matte on the original logo to Alpha Matte.  It will use the alpha of the layer above. You may need to press the "Toggle Switches/Masks" button to reveal the Track Matte options on the layer:
[image]
Do the reveal animation by adding a Trim Path to your Shape Layer:
[image: grab4]